# When Ubuntu 21.04 will release?

Tags: release-management

**When **Ubuntu 21.04** will release? I'm waiting from the beginning of this year.**

Comment: See for yourself here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: If I ask my favorite search engine "*when will Ubuntu 21.04 be released?*" it returns an accurate answer and source for that answer. Also, the release numbering quite famously follows a YY.MM format -- 04 refers to April.

Answer (score 2):

21.04 means the 2021-April release.

As all standard Ubuntu releases use the *year.month* format, it's easy to know when a release came out, and when future releases will come out.

eg.

- 18.04 means the 2018-April release.
- 20.04 means the 2020-April release.
- 20.10 means the 2020-October release.

so

- 21.04 will be the 2021-April release (it's referred to as *hirsute* or *hirsute hippo* until release time when it will become 21.04 as all Ubuntu *development* releases are)

**Specialist Releases use *year* format**

Ubuntu also have specialist releases that use the *year* format, eg. Ubuntu Core 18 meaning the 2018 release, Ubuntu Core 20 meaning the 2020 release, but these are *snap* only and intended for device, appliance and cloud use, so not general server or desktop intended purposes.

**Releases are April & October with one exception**

With one minor exception, Ubuntu releases are usually the April and October of each year.  The first LTS was in 2006-June, ie. late and it was thus called Ubuntu 6.06 LTS (the only non-April LTS release).

**Predicting date of future releases even if no schedule exists**

Releases are always on a Thursday, scheduled to not be the last thursday of the month (3rd usually) as it provides a week to push the schedule back if necessary and keep it in the month.

For 21.04/hirsute hippo, the schedule can be found at

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-schedule/18539

**Knowing when a release reaches End-of-Support easier too**

Knowing when a release reaches *end-of-life* is also made easier. Non LTS (*long-term-support*) releases have  9 months of supported life, so you can add 9 to the month (20.10 + 9 = 21.07 EOL) and know when you need to *release-upgrade* to the next release. Ubuntu LTS releases have 5 years of *standard support*, where as flavors have only 3 years. Standard support for LTS releases can be extended via ESM.

Comment: In the predicting the date, if the month has 5 thursdays, it's usually the 4th thursday.  I could have worded that differently (2nd last thursday of month), but I felt 3rd thursday was better as most months have 4 thursdays...  Better to always check the schedule anyway (20.04.2 release date got moved at least twice) so I didn't provide the date by choice.

Comment: Upvoting because this is true of course but I'm of the mindset there should be a release when something is new (and stable!) not a release just because the calendar demands something.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yeah I love Debian too :)   (the stable applies there, the 'new' maybe not so much, they're somewhat calendar based too)

Answer (score 0):

April 22nd 2021 (according to [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hirsute)).